# Why is Class function working if class is mentioned in function call but not if the object instantized is used in function call in python?

Tags: python, function, class, recursion

The above code works but the second code shows  typerror: print(a.factorial(a, 5))TypeError: factorial() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given:

```
class Factorial:
def factorial(self, num):
     if num == 0:
        return 1
     if num ==1:
        return 1
     else:
        return num * self.factorial(self, num-1)

def main():
a = Factorial()
print(Factorial.factorial(Factorial, 5))
main()
```

The second code is as follows:

```
class Factorial:
def factorial(self, num):
     if num == 0:
        return 1
     if num ==1:
        return 1
     else:
        return num * self.factorial(self, num-1)

def main():
a = Factorial()
print(a.factorial(a, 5))
main()
```

Comment: you might find this video interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8moWQ1561FY

Answer (score 0):

`self` argument is the same as the object on which you call the function. You don't need to provide it again as the first explicit argument - `a.factorial(5)` will work.

Comment: But when I use a.factorial(5). Why does it show this error: TypeError: factorial() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given?

Comment: `return num * self.factorial...`

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method on an instance (rather than on the class), the instance is automatically passed as the `self` argument.  You don't pass it yourself.

So this:

```
Factorial.factorial(a, 5)
```

is the same as this:

```
a.factorial(5)
```

and this:

```
a.factorial(a, 5)
```

is the same as this:

```
Factorial.factorial(a, a, 5)  # too many arguments!
```

Note that your function definition is also confused about the difference between instances and classes.  Given that this is an instance method, it should expect `self` to be an *instance* of `Factorial`, not the `Factorial` class itself:

```
def factorial(self, num):
     if num == 0:
        return 1
     if num ==1:
        return 1
     else:
        return num * self.factorial(num-1)  # no extra "self" arg
```

Once you make this fix, calling this method as `Factorial.factorial(Factorial, 5)` will not work, because that's not a valid way to call an instance method (it "works" in your current code because of that `self` bug that prevents it from working as an actual instance method).

To define it as a class method (where the first argument is the class, not an instance), you'd do:

```
@classmethod
def factorial(cls, num):
     if num == 0:
        return 1
     if num ==1:
        return 1
     else:
        return num * cls.factorial(num-1)
```

and then would call it as `Factorial.factorial(5)`.

Comment: But when I use a.factorial(5). Why does it show this error: TypeError: factorial() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given?

Comment: I assume that's happening in the recursive call, due to the `self.factorial(self, num-1)` bug.  Remove the extra `self` from that call and it'll work (and then your `Factorial.factorial(Factorial, 5)` one will break, but that one should never have worked).